# Fonts error on Firefox in my theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I completed with a template built by using Bootstrap 3. Everything is fine but have a problem with Firefox. I'm using H2 and H5 tags for heading for each section of the page. In Firefox it shows the half font size for H2 and H5 tags. For paragraph texts everything is ok. Please help me out with this one and your help will be highly appreciated. You can view the demo using Firefox http://demos.themesfinity.com/simplifinity

Comment: Please show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve that by adding

```
font-weight: 400;
```

To your .title h2 class

```
.title h2 {
   font-weight: 400;
   /* etc ... */
}
```

At least it worked for me!

IMO I think it's so important to add a font weight in order to avoid these browsers problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and will surely see towards your guidelines.